# What's the meaning of "Memory allocator" in Node's --trace-gc-verbose output?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to debug a NodeJS application that uses too much memory. Although the max old space size is set to 200 MBs, the node process memory usage hovers at around 400 MBs. I'm trying to understand what's using all this memory.

I tried `node --trace-gc --trace-gc-verbose`, which produced the following output:

```
[164:0x3851b20] Fast promotion mode: false survival rate: 19%
[164:0x3851b20]   107420 ms: [HeapController] factor 1.1 based on mu=0.970, speed_ratio=5872 (gc=501591, mutator=85)
[164:0x3851b20]   107420 ms: [HeapController] Limit: old size: 165708 KB, new limit: 183302 KB (1.1)
[164:0x3851b20]   107420 ms: [GlobalMemoryController] Limit: old size: 165708 KB, new limit: 183302 KB (1.1)
[164:0x3851b20]   107420 ms: Scavenge 162.7 (185.8) -> 161.9 (185.8) MB, 1.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.998, current mu = 0.999) allocation failure 
[164:0x3851b20] Memory allocator,       used: 190224 KB, available:  26864 KB
[164:0x3851b20] Read-only space,        used:     31 KB, available:    224 KB, committed:    256 KB
[164:0x3851b20] New space,              used:    115 KB, available:    907 KB, committed:   1024 KB
[164:0x3851b20] New large object space, used:      0 KB, available:   1022 KB, committed:      0 KB
[164:0x3851b20] Old space,              used: 127259 KB, available:  21344 KB, committed: 148844 KB
[164:0x3851b20] Code space,             used:   1051 KB, available:    260 KB, committed:   1440 KB
[164:0x3851b20] Map space,              used:   1926 KB, available:   1146 KB, committed:   3076 KB
[164:0x3851b20] Large object space,     used:  35471 KB, available:      0 KB, committed:  35536 KB
[164:0x3851b20] Code large object space,     used:      3 KB, available:      0 KB, committed:     48 KB
[164:0x3851b20] All spaces,             used: 165858 KB, available:  51769 KB, committed: 190224 KB
[164:0x3851b20] Unmapper buffering 3 chunks of committed:    768 KB
[164:0x3851b20] External memory reported:  38062 KB
[164:0x3851b20] Backing store memory:  37334 KB
[164:0x3851b20] External memory global 0 KB
[164:0x3851b20] Total time spent in GC  : 1045.1 ms
```

I'm trying to understand the meaning of the "Memory allocator" line. Extensive documentation is available for the purpose of every space in the output, but I can't figure out what does this line mean. Is this the amount of RAM used by the allocator itself, and if so, why would it be so high?